# Symfony: ajax form load

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

currently I have a new action in my index.html.twig file.

```
        <div id="formcontent">
            form content goes here
        </div>
        <a href="{{ path('uni_new') }}">Create a new uni</a>
```

and my new action looks like this

```
 /**
 * Creates a new uni entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="uni_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $uni = new Uni();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UniType', $uni);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($uni);
        $em->flush($uni);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('uni_show', array('id' => $uni->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('uni/new.html.twig', array(
        'uni' => $uni,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I want this new action to be done by ajax request. So when a user click on `Create a new uni`, instead of going to a new url, I want the form to be loaded by ajax call and replace the content of the above div with id `formcontent`. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The PHP code you displayed is OK overall, what you need is JS centric and has nothing to do with Symfony. You should probably add your JS code there.

Answer (score 1):

For an ajax call, all a `Symfony controller` can do is responding the form HTML only with a `json` format.

```
/**
 * Creates a new uni entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="uni_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $uni = new Uni();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UniType', $uni);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($uni);
        $em->flush($uni);

        /**
         * If your form also need a ajax submit, respond output accordingly.
         */

        return $this->redirectToRoute('uni_show', array('id' => $uni->getId()));
    }

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $formHtml = $this->renderView('uni/new.html.twig', array(
            'uni' => $uni,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
        return new JsonResponse(
            array(
                'success' => true,
                'formHtml' => $formHtml
            )
        );
    }

    return $this->render('uni/new.html.twig', array(
        'uni' => $uni,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Use `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()` to detect if its an ajax call, and respond accordingly, The `jQuery.ajax` should take care of rest in terms of form replacement to the div.

Note : Code not tested.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
(function submitHandler() {
    var $form = $("#your_form_id");
    $form.on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
            .done(function (data) {
                $form.replaceWith(data);
                submitHandler();
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR) {
                if(jqXHR.status === 302) {
                    location.href = jqXHR.responseJSON;
                } else {
                    location.href = Routing.generate('registration_fail')
                }
            })
    })
})();
```

});

You have to add some js to your frontend. In this code I use JQUERY.

Some additional code in your Controller, when your form is Valid

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                return new JsonResponse($this->generateUrl('registration_success'), 302);
            }
```

You have to remember that Redirect in controller not working for You, when You use Ajax request, so you have to redirect your customer in frontend